# Ford Fiesta and Focus Clutch Issues

Tags: ford, clutch, focus, fiesta, clio

I am in the UK and I am currently planning to get a Ford Focus/Fiesta depending on the budget and features. I have viewed 2 Fords so far - a Focus (100K miles, 2001 model) and a Fiesta (35k miles, 2008 model). The Focus had a very stiff clutch, but the Fiesta had a slightly smoother, but still relatively stiff clutch. The gear in the Fiesta is quite smooth, so I can feel that the car is releatively newer. Because I am used to a small Vauxhall Corsa which has a very good clutch.

I have seen quite old cars such as Skoda with 66k miles, but the clutch was much better and smoother compared to Ford. That's what confuses me the most.

Is this issue quite common with the Fords? I am getting a feeling that the Fords are not very well with clutches. Does anyone has any experience. Also, If I can get the clutch work done and get it smoother, how much will it cost me?

Any help/advice is appreciated!!!

P.S. I also found the same problem with Renault Clios

Answer (score 1):

The clutches on all cars will vary in 'stiffness' as any particular model of vehicle will have variations of engine size and performance. Corsa and Fiesta are smaller cars and a light clutch is appreciated by a host of people, especially the girls. There are no real problems with the clutches on the cars you mentioned, including Renault, and the issues you outline are either based on limited experiance of the vehicles you mention, or are a hangover from your previous cars clutch.

Comment: Well, I don't agree because I have bought a Mitsubishi Colt and have driven various cars (older/newer) in the process. The clutch is really good and smooth. Except German cars, all the other European cars seem to have a really stiff clutch. I guess it's purely down to owner's lack of interest in maintaining their cars (not everyone though!)

Comment: Over time I have driven literally thousands of cars, vans and trucks. From side valve Fords to now, brand new built last week Peugeots. (Include American models with the United States Naval Activities, posted in the UK.) They do differ to suit application, and market.